# Adding a User email to show who edited row ; currently reflects date and time need user information

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, timestamp

My current script has the timestamps, but I'm unsure of how I can add the email address to identify the user that edited the spreadsheet.

The current script is:

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT-8";
  var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "Retailer";
  var timeStampColName = "Last Edited";
  var event= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Retail Orders'); //Name of 
  the sheet where you want to run this script.


  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 
  sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = 
  updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only 
  timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row 
  itself!
  var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
  cell.setValue(date);
  }
}


function onEdit(e) 
{
var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
if(sh.getName() !== 'Retail Orders' || e.range.rowStart < 1 || 
e.range.columnStart < 1 || e.range.columnStart > 18) return;
  sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new 
  Date(), "GMT-8", "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss"))
}
```

Any ideas of how I can add usernames to automatically update in column 2, right after the timestamp in column 1?

Comment: Research about `Session.getUser().getEmail()`

Comment: Related: [Why is my Google spreadsheet script not capturing emails on getUser()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46373478/1595451)